# Send an example newsletter to individual e-mail

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

As far as i know, anyone can't manage groups to send the newsletter, but ,could i send a newsletter template to my individual e-mail to check if it's correctly done?

As i see, i could manage the file:

> /app/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php

Method :  `getSubscribersCollection()` - line 125

code:

```
$this->_subscribersCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('newsletter/subscriber_collection')
                ->addFieldToFilter('subscriber_email', 'my-test@email.com')
                ->useQueue($this);
```

it's that correct?

Any other way?

I need to be sure, because i don't want to mail wrong to customers.

Comment: To check my templates and make sure everything works fine a added a second storeView and only subscriped my email address. When adding the newsletter to a new queue chose the second storeView and only you will receive the mail. When everything is fine start the queue with the real storeView.

Comment: @NiGe it's a solition yes, but i want to implement this to could make it easier than this.